# Regular expression for mining content of a file

Tags: python, regex, text-mining

I have a text file like below:

```
<Author>Marilyn1949
<Content>great way of doing things.
can you provide more info.blah blah blah..  
<Date>Dec 1, 2008...
(file content continues in similar fashion for other authors)"
```

I am trying to extract the content section using the code below. Can you help me figure out what am i missing as my file is just an getting genrated as an array of [].

```
text_file = open("output/out.txt", "w")
for file in os.listdir("./"):
    if glob.fnmatch.fnmatch(file, '*.txt'):
        with open(file, "r") as source:
            L= source.read()                
            pattern =  re.compile(r'<Content>*<Date>')              
            for match in L:
                result = re.findall(r'<Content>.*<Date>', match)
                text_file.write(str(result))
                text_file.write('\n')
```

Comment: thank you for editing Tichodrama.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dot character matches anything except a newline. Use the [`re.DOTALL` flag](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#contents-of-module-re) to make it match newlines as well:

```
result = re.findall(r'<Content>.*<Date>', match, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

Also, you might not want to capture the tags:

```
result = re.findall(r'<Content>(.*)<Date>', match, flags=re.DOTALL)
```

And cleaning up your example a bit:

```
with open(file, "r") as source:
    results = re.findall(r'<Content>(.*?)<Date>', source.read(), flags=re.DOTALL)
    text_file.write('\n'.join(results))
```

Comment: type error: expected string or buffer. Do i need to convert to str before writing or use dictionary?